# Is there a better way to format this string?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there a better way to format this string?

```
var Mac = sdr.GetString(0);
string trimMac = Mac.Replace("-", "");
string formatMac = trimMac.Insert(4, ".");
string formatAgain = formatMac.Insert(9, ".");
string dudeWTF = formatAgain.Trim();
```

I am pulling mac address's from a database, then I format them from XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX to XXXX.XXXX.XXXX then i am using a `StreamWriter` to write them to a file. sdr is a `SqlDataReader`.

Comment: What's the input and expected output?

Comment: what is your purpose to format it? and what is your expected input and output string?

Comment: At the very least, it's probably not wise to `Trim()` at the beginning. If trimming is to remove excessive whitespace from user input, then you're changing where the two `.` characters end up for equivalent input.

Comment: Consider updating your original question with the information in your comment. The question will live for a long time, and right now, its not very useful (but it could be).

Answer (score 6):

Starting with a string like: `String mac="XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX";`

Then we can just do:

`String dudeWTF = String.Format("{0}{1}.{2}{3}.{4}{5}", mac.Split('-'));`

Comment: This is a novel way of performing the operation. I like how it chains the split results into the params parameter of string.Format. Nicely done.

Comment: @ToddBowles: Thanks.  Funnily enough I didn't know you could do that with arrays until I tried it when optimizing a bit prior to posting.

Answer (score 1):

```
string dudeWTF = Mac.Replace("-", "").Insert(4, ".").Insert(9, ".").Trim();
```

Comment: Based on the limited information you provided in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Why do something simple, when you can use a...

**REGULAR EXPRESSION**

```
private static readonly string _InnerPattern = "([a-zA-Z0-9]{2})";
private static readonly string _Pattern = string.Format("{0}-{0}-{0}-{0}-{0}-{0}", _InnerPattern);
private static readonly string _ReplacePattern = "$1$2.$3$4.$5$6";
private static readonly Regex _TransformRegex = new Regex(_Pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled);
public static string TransformMacAddressUsingRegex(string input)
{
    return _TransformRegex.Replace(input, _ReplacePattern);
}
```

The expression above creates a capture group for each set of characters separated by a hyphen "-", then constructs the output string using the contents of those capture groups.

Now for the bad news, its almost **5 times slower** than the originally supplied code, and approx. **2.5 times slower** than @RobertHarvey's solution, as well as being remarkably more complicated. This is actually an improvement over my first cut, which was **66** times slower than the originally supplied code and **37** times slower than @RobertHarvey's solution.

Timing was measured by repeatedly transforming the same string 1 million times in a for loop and timing with a `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch`.

I post this answer because at some point someone is going to think "why not a regular expression!" (like me) and because I spent far too long on this. Maybe someone will find this useful.